# div to specified div cloning

Tags: jquery

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TQdrH/15/

Currently that fiddle is set up to essentially do a .each() - Instead of .each(), I would like to specify the duplication, here is an example:

```
HTML

<div id="title">Book Title</div>
<div id="price">$20</div>
<div id="description">A book about something</div>


CSS

#title, #price, #description {display: none;}  // These would not be displayed on the page.
```

The goal now, is to randomly put div's on a page in different areas and to specify, which piece I want cloned and where.  For example:

```
HTML

<div id="duplicate-title"></div>

<div id="duplicate-price"></div>

<div id="duplicate-description"></div>
```

So now, based on where I place the above div's in a page, the data from the original div's would be cloned to the ones marked with "duplicate-" followed by the name of the original div.

I've been having trouble with this and would appreciate any help.  Thanks!

Comment: what is the problem? it seems to be working

Comment: It is in a .each - if you remove the duplicate div's it will still add them to the "real-content".  The div's I want duplicated will be scattered around the page and this current fiddle will not work for that.

Comment: So you want to clone only those divs which are added to the `real-content` div. ie if `duplicate-item3` is not added to `real-content` then you do not want to clone it. Am I correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, then we will fetch all the div's whose id starts with `duplicate-` and then clone the original

If it is correct, [try this](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/TQdrH/20/).

```
$('[id^="duplicate-"]').each(function () {
    var $this = $(this).empty();
    var id = $this.attr('id');
    var idToCopy = id.substring(10);
    var $newDiv = $this.replaceWith($('#' + idToCopy).clone().attr('id', id))
});
```

Comment: Sort of, here is the only problem: http://jsfiddle.net/TQdrH/17/ - Let's say instead of "#real-content div" it is just inside of "body" - Needs to be able to show other content as well.

Comment: So I think we can look for elements whose id starts with `duplicate-` is it enough?